# Getting attribute value using Selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium

This is my html page i want to parse:

```
<html lang="en-US" data-ismobile="false">
    <body ond="return false;" onselect="return false;" textmenu="return false">
        <div id="wrap">
            <form id="frm1" method="post">
                <input name="Token" type="hidden" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                <input type="hidden" name="cate" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="sub" value="7">
            </form>
            <form id="frm2" method="post">
                <input name="Token" type="hidden" value="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY">
                <input type="hidden" name="cate" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="sub" value="7">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get `name` & `value`  attributes from form `frm1`

So far i have come up with following code:

```
IWebElement _frm1 = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("frm1")); //this should find me a correct form
token_frm1 = _frm1 .GetAttribute("value"); //this i know is inccorect
```

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I can't. Its internal website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form` node has neither `@name` nor `@value`. Try to get attribute values from child `input`node

```
IWebElement _frm1 = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("frm1"));
IWebElement _input = _frm1.FindElement(By.Name("Token"));
token_frm1 = _input .GetAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 1):

The *name* and *value* attributes are within the `<input>` tag. To extract the value of the *name* and *value* attribute you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Extract value of *name* attribute:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='frm1']//input")).GetAttribute("name"));
  ```
- Extract value of *value* attribute:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='frm1']//input")).GetAttribute("value"));
  ```

---

### Update

There are multiple `<input>` elements with *`name`* and *`value`* attribute. So to extract the value of the *name* and *value* attribute from `<frm1>` you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Extract value of *name* attribute:

  ```
  IList < IWebElement > elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//form[@id='frm1']//input"));
  foreach(IWebElement e in elements) {
      System.Console.WriteLine(e.GetAttribute("name"));
  ```
- Extract value of *value* attribute:

  ```
  IList < IWebElement > elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//form[@id='frm1']//input"));
  foreach(IWebElement e in elements) {
      System.Console.WriteLine(e.GetAttribute("value"));
  ```

Comment: I have a different question, how can we create selenium object using just agiven html eg say obove, I tried `obj = selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement ('<a></a>')` so that I can use the functions `obj.find_element` etc function on it becuase this gives me error

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar That's a different question and offtopic for this question. Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.